# how to create a new postgis database for usage with QGIS under windows

Tags: qgis, postgis-1.5

After installing postgresql with postgis under windows xp I have 3 databases:

```
postgis
postgres
template_postgis
```

now I try to create a new spatially enabled database in pgAdminIII: I select template_postgis in the pgAdminIII object browser and via rightclick in the context-menu I select  `new object ->new database`.
when I try to use this  database in QGIS with the spit-plugin I get the following error message:

> the chosen database does not have PostGIS installed, but this is
>   required for storage of spatial data.

How do I create a working spatial postgis database?
please help a rookie

thanks

Kurt

Comment: selecting template_postgis  and then clicking into the PgAdmin III toolbar to "create a new object of the same type as the selected object" (= blue arrow -icon) also doesnt work

Comment: I did follow Stéphane's tip：Right-click on any database, choose New Database, fill Name and Owner and, under Template, choose template_postgis. Let me know if that works? But when I Right-click on any database, choose New Database, fill Name and Owner and, under Template, choose template_postgis......, I got an error told me that this template, say template_postgis_20, is being used by other users, so I can't create an new database, how can I do？

Comment: I had the same error after initially installing PostGIS/PosgreSQL with PgAdmin.  After rebooting, I didn't get the error message and the new postgis database was created

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Right-click on any database, choose *New Database*, fill *Name* and *Owner*  and, under Template, choose **template_postgis**. Let me know if that works?

Comment: Stéphane, it works - thank you very much for your support. choosing the template_postgis did the trick!!

Comment: Good, by the way, to check that your DB is PostGIS-enabled, verify that you have the tables geometry_columns and spatial_ref_sys in your schema public. And also the view geography_columns (as of PostGIS 1.5, I believe)

Answer (score 2):

Within PgAdmin make a new database. Then click on the database, click on the `SQL` icon
[image]

In the `SQL` paste the following line:

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
```

Then press the `run` icon. That should create the postgis functionality in that database.

---

This approach works for PostGIS 2.0, but not apparently for PostGIS 1.5 ( I tested both on Win 7).

Comment: clenius, on my system this prodcues an error: no such file or directory SQL State 58P01

Comment: clenius, thank  you for your support! yes i am using Postgis 1.5 ps. after further investigations I found an other way to make a nonspatial database spatial is to run the deliver postgis.sql. this should work also on non-windos-systems