# PostGIS template1 database missing

Tags: postgis

I want to create a template_postgis for connecting PostGIS via QGIS

So I follow the step on following page

[how to create a new postgis database for usage with QGIS under windows](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21182/how-to-create-a-new-postgis-database-for-usage-with-qgis-under-windows)

But when I follow the steps there's a problem happened

```
createdb: database creation failed: ERROR:  template database "template1" does not exist
```

So I google it for answer but no one can help me to create a template1 database!

Any suggestion?

Comment: Please check out http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21182/how-to-create-a-new-postgis-database-for-usage-with-qgis-under-windows if it helps

Comment: it's the page I mention in my post I follow the page and problem happen

Comment: Depending on PostGIS version, you may find that you can just add the PostGIS extension to your database, no need to create a database called template1.

Answer (score 0):

It's unusual for a PostgreSQL instance not to have a 'template1' database, but if you don't, you can just create it.

To quote [PostgreSQL docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/manage-ag-templatedbs.html):

> template1 and template0 do not have any special status beyond the fact
> that the name template1 is the default source database name for CREATE
> DATABASE. For example, one could drop template1 and recreate it from
> template0 without any ill effects.

I would begin by trying:

```
CREATE DATABASE template1 TEMPLATE template0;
```